# java else without if error

Tags: java

I have wrote this in java and keep getting an else without if error. I have gone over it over and over and can not find the error. Is it really a missing if or is their a problem with the rest of the program?

```
public class Password {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        //int Counter = 0;

         String[] UserName = {
            "William Whitcomb" , "Pamela Healy" ,
            "Dennis Clark" , "Troy Bingham" ,
            "Bill Mauler"
         };
        String[] Password = {
            "WWhit0523" , "PHeal0854" ,
            "DClar1053" , "TBing1272" ,
            "BMaul0968"
         };
          String EnterName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( "Enter a valid user name.",     //Name pane window
          "User Name");
          String EnterPassword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( "Enter a valid password.",       //Age pane window
          "Password");
          for (int Counter = 0; Counter < UserName.length;){
            Validate();
            if (Validate() = true) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You entered the User Name of " + UserName[Counter] +
                "and the password of " + Password[Counter]);  //Results pane
                }
            }   //End of for
        }  //End of Method


        Boolean Validate(String EnterName , String EnterPassword){
                Boolean Condition = false;

                    if (EnterName.equals(UserName[Counter])) {
                        if (EnterPassword.equals(Password[Counter])) {
                        Condition = true;
                        return //Condition;
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have entered an invalid password.");
                            Counter += 1;
                                }    //End of Inner Else

                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have entered an invalid user name.");
                        Counter += 1;
                        }  //End of Outer Else
                } //End of outer if
            }  //End of Method
    }   //End of Class
```

Comment: Please use an IDE. You have several basic problems in your code that a good tool would have helped you resolve.

Comment: @William Whitcomb, see my answer

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is on this line:

```
return //Condition;
```

You commented out the semicolon by accident, prompting an unrelated parse error down the road.

On a somewhat related note, when your function returns a `boolean`, you should not compare the result to `true` or `false`. Just write `if (Validate())...` or `if (!Validate())...` instead.

Comment: This seems like the right answer - it ends that 'if' and gets to 'else'.

Answer (score 2):

At least one error I see:
`Validate() = true` should be `Validate() == true`. You are assigning instead of using comparison.

Even shorter, `if(Validate())` will work.

But the error itself is most probably caused by the missing semicolon after return it seems.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped. Now the only error I am getting is error : class, interface or enum expected } //End of Class

Comment: You're missing } or have an extra { somewhere, just double-check your code, it should be pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need

```
} //End of outer if
```

since you already closed it before `else`. Remove this line.

Take a look at formatted version of your code

```
Boolean Validate(String EnterName, String EnterPassword) {
    Boolean Condition = false;

    if (EnterName.equals(UserName[Counter])) {
        if (EnterPassword.equals(Password[Counter])) {
            Condition = true;
            return Condition;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You have entered an invalid password.");
            Counter += 1;
        } // End of Inner Else

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "You have entered an invalid user name.");
        Counter += 1;
    } // End of Outer Else
--> } //End of outer if                 <-- You don't want this line
} // End of Method
```

Comment: +1 for the 'formatted version" part. Good formatting really does make code that much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I saw One extra } in the method validate. I mean one more } is in the method validate(). please see your code carefully. Please remove it. and ; missing in the return statement. The method should be as

```
Boolean Validate(String EnterName , String EnterPassword){
            Boolean Condition = false;
                if (EnterName.equals(UserName[Counter])) 
                {
                    if (EnterPassword.equals(Password[Counter])) 
                    {
                    Condition = true;
                    return;
                    } 
                else 
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have entered an invalid password.");
                        Counter += 1;
                    }    //End of Inner Else

                } // if closed here
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have entered an invalid user name.");
                    Counter += 1;
                    }  //End of Outer Else
        }  //End of Method
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a list of things you need to change:

- You have an extra brace at the very end of your class. Remove it.
- Your `Validate` method is using variables `UserName`, `Counter` and `Password` which are never declared anywhere
- Your `Validate` method has a `return` statement that is not terminated by a semi-colon
- Your main method, in the for loop, both calls to `Validate` are made without arguments (you need two of them)
- Your main method, your first call to `Validate` is effectively a no-op (you don't do anything with the return value). Remove it.

All these problems would have been highlighted by a halfway decent IDE. I would highly recommend using one.

Comment: Unfortunately my instructor has us using text pad which sucks. What would be a good IDE?

Comment: The UserName, Counter and Password I assumed where passed from the main method. How do you pass those values to the Validate method.

Comment: There are several good ones. Alot of learning institutions use BlueJ - thats basically a starter IDE. Some of the more 'regular ones' - Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ.

Comment: You declared all `UserName`, `Counter`, and `Password` in your main method, but `UserName` and `Password` should be class variables, and `Counter` should be passed declared in your `Validate` method (the whole for loop should be moved there actually).

Comment: Which version of Eclipse should I download. I am running Windows 7. There is a monstrous list on their site.

Comment: The latest version of Eclipse IDE for Java Developers has pretty much all you need. Here's a link directly to it - http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junosr1.